# Delay first function call for n-seconds

Tags: javascript

I'm having a javascript function which I have set an interval to execute every 30 seconds. This is my code:

```
function ping() {
    // code ...
}

ping(); // call function when page loads for first time

// call function every 30 seconds
window.setInterval(function(){
    ping();
}, 30000);
```

What I'd like to do is to delay the first call (right when the page loads for first time) for 5 seconds and then the function should execute again every 30 secs.

I have tried the `setTimeout`, but doesn't seem to work, it executes imidiatelly any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

```
setTimeout(ping(), 5000); // delay first call for 5 secs

// call function every 30 seconds
    window.setInterval(function(){
        ping();
    }, 30000);
```

Comment: Change `setTimeout(ping(), 5000);` to `setTimeout(ping, 5000);`. `()` followed by function name will call it immediately.

Comment: This should work if you remove the () in the call to ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are not waiting until timeout to declare the interval function.

There is a few different ways to do that, so let me suggest one:

```
function ping() {
    // code ...
}

setTimeout(function () {

    ping(); // call function when page loads for first time

    // call function every 30 seconds
    window.setInterval(function(){
        ping();
    }, 30000);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to work as expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it immediately on `setTimeout(ping(), 5000);`. You are setting the result of `ping()` as the timeout function. If you want `ping` to be called by the timeout, then either do `setTimeout(ping, 5000);` or wrap it in a closure, like you did the second time.